# ServiceStack ORMLite How to fparse JSON data in Query

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following model structure.

```
public class Inforamation 
{ 
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public InfoMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class InfoMetadata 
{ 
  // Bike Info

  public string BikeName { get; set; }
  public string ModelNumber { get; set; }

  // House Info
  public string HouseName { get; set; }
  public string HouseNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Request DTO

```
public class RequestDto
{ 
public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

//Service

```
 public void Get(RequestDto request)
    {
      var query = Db.From<Inforamation>();
    
      query = query.And<Inforamation>(v => v.Name == query || v.InfoMetadata.BikeName == query);

var result = Db.select(query);
    
    }
```

My database table structure is like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Id      |   Name    |Metadata                               |
|           |           |                                       |
|      1    |  Bhushan  |{"houseName": 'ABC', "BikeName": "VC"} |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

//Error getting on Db.Select(query);

```
The multi-part identifier "InfoMetadata .BikeName " could not be bound.'
```

Can some one please told me how to parse that type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex Types are blobbed by default in OrmLite using their [configured Complex Type Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers) which you typically can't perform server side queries on, so you shouldn't blob fields you want to be able to query with SQL as they can only be inspected after the resultsets are materialized in C#.

If you're using **PostgreSQL** you can [use its rich JSON Data Type](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#json-data-types) by annotating Complex Type properties with `[PgSqlJson]` or `[PgSqlJsonB]` attributes, e.g:

```
public class TableJson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [PgSqlJson]
    public ComplexType ComplexTypeJson { get; set; }

    [PgSqlJsonB]
    public ComplexType ComplexTypeJsonb { get; set; }
}

db.Insert(new TableJson
{
    Id = 1,
    ComplexTypeJson = new ComplexType {
        Id = 2, SubType = new SubType { Name = "JSON" }
    },
    ComplexTypeJsonb = new ComplexType {
        Id = 3, SubType = new SubType { Name = "JSONB" }
    },
});
```

Where they can then be queried on the server with [PostgreSQL's JSON SQL Syntax and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html):

```
var result = db.Single<TableJson>("table_json->'SubType'->>'Name' = 'JSON'");
```

Otherwise you will only be able to query the results on the client using LINQ in C# after executing the Server query, e.g:

```
var results = Db.Select(Db.From<Information>().Where(x => x.Name == query));
var filteredResults = results.Where(x => x.InfoMetadata.BikeName == query).ToList();
```

Comment: You mean If I have to fetch the data from the server then I need to add metadata fields in the Information model. If I have to query those fields right?

Comment: @BhushanDhage No if you want to query JSON on the server in PostgreSQL you need to annotate the Complex Type property. Otherwise you can only query it on the client after executing the server query, see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Actually I'm using an SQL server and I want to compare that metadata fields in the query itself,. like in runtime SQL query.